# Is it possible to check if a function with a string as its name exists?(C++)

Tags: c++, string, function

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
if (Is_Function("helloworld")
    // Run code
```

Comment: No. Why do you want to do this? There's probably another way.

Comment: This is possible in scripting languages like Lua, and you *might* be able to do something tricky in languages like Java or C# with their reflection, but it's definitely not possible in C++ unless you've done something like make a map of strings to function pointers. Why do you want to do this? There is almost certainly a better solution to whatever your problem is.

Comment: What's the exact question ? You want to know if a function name `helloworld()` existing ?

Comment: What does `// Run code` contain? If it contains a call to `helloworld()`, then you'd better have a declaration for the function available otherwise you'll simply get a compile error. And if you have a declaration, then you know it exists (or the linker will tell you if it doesn't).

Comment: Why in C++ world anyone demand that? In 13 years of working in C++ I neither thought of doing something like this, nor I faced any situation where I would need this. What exactly you are looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple answer: no

Complicated answer: yes if debugging symbols are turned on and you write some helper functions to look through the debug symbols. But this is really horrible, buggy (functions can be automatically inlined and will be magically absent from your symbol table), and most of all stops working as soon as you build the release version of the program.

Final answer: **no**

Answer (score 3):

Not in any normal sense, since C++ doesn't support reflection.  You could compile the program with debug information and have it open itself and read its symbol table like a debugger would, but that's probably more trouble than it's worth.

Anyway, why do you need to detect existence of a function at runtime?  That's known at compile time.

If you can separate out the part that *might* contain the function into a dynamic library, you could open it at runtime and do a symbol lookup on it.  (On a Linux system you'd use `dlopen()` and `dlsym()`; there are equivalents on other platforms but I don't know their names offhand.)  This will tell you whether the name exists as a symbol, though it won't tell you whether it's a function.

Answer (score 2):

One technique you can use on ELF-based systmes (Linux and most Unix variants, including MacOS X), is to link with `-rdynamic`, and then call `dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "helloworld")` to get a pointer to the function `helloworld` if it exists in the current executable or any shared lib that has been loaded.  This has issues with C++ due to name mangling, so really only works for functions declared with `extern "C"` or in C code.

Comment: +1. This is exactly how to do it; I've seen it done in anger when loading a shared libary at run-time and not knowing for certain in advance if certain functions will be present. This allows a fall-back to be defined. Anyone know the Windows equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Qt does something like this when using signals and slots, but then the functions will be registered in a map indexed by a mangling of their name iirc. This registering is achieved by their "MetaObject Compiler" which is basically a preprocessor/code generator and works statically.

Depending on what you want to do, you could use Qt.

Another possibility would be to compile a shared library and use dlsym, if available on your system.